# Is it possible to set the default behaviour of double clicking a folder to be "Open in New Window" with PCManFM?

Tags: lxde, pcmanfm

My mother uses separate desktops heavily and finds it very irritating when she accidentally double-clicks on a folder on her desktop rather than right-clicking and choosing "open in new window" as she's trained herself to usually do.

Is there a way to set PCManFM to default to opening in new windows rather than new tabs?

(She's using 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) at the moment)

Here's a [very rushed screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yci0MJgKRIU) explaining the behaviour I'm talking about.

Comment: I've looked in Edit->Preferences and there is no such option. So my guess is that the answer is "No".

Comment: I follow the LXDE dev blog. Options which aren't exposed via the GUI yet aren't unheard of in PCManFM.

Comment: The only answer I've found to this is to just recompile PCManFM with a parameter changed.  I don't have the link handy, but I found it through Google on either the Crunchbang or Arch forums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to recompile PCManFM , I am running ***Lubuntu 12.04*** with ***PCManFM 0.9.10*** and these steps worked for me.

Follow these steps:

1. Open a Terminal and install the necessary packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install apt-src build-essential
   ```
2. Install the build dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep pcmanfm
   ```
3. Create a folder to download the source code:

   ```
   mkdir ~/Downloads/src
   cd ~/Downloads/src
   ```
4. Download the source:

   ```
   apt-src install -b pcmanfm
   ```
5. Edit the `pcmanfm-0.9.10/src/pcmanfm.c` file.

   ```
   leafpad pcmanfm-0.9.10/src/pcmanfm.c
   ```
6. In Leafpad, search for the line `fm_main_win_open_in_last_active(fi->path);` (should be somewhere around line 420 and change it to `fm_main_win_add_win(NULL, fi->path);`.
   Save the changes and close the file. See the screenshots if it isn't clear:

   **Before:**

   [image: code earlier]

   **After:**

   [image: code after editing]
7. Go to the `pcmanfm-0.9.10/` folder to build the deb packages:

   ```
   cd pcmanfm-0.9.10/
   dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b
   ```
8. Now you can install the deb packages:

   ```
   cd ..
   sudo dpkg -i pcmanfm*deb
   ```
9. Finally you can logout and Login to see the changes.

---

Reference: [This post by **ogilvierothchild** in ubuntu forums.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1908610&p=11690664#post11690664)

Answer (score 2):

Edit this file (as root):

```
/usr/share/applications/pcmanfm.desktop
```

Look near the end of it for a line that says:

```
Exec=pcmanfm %U
```

Add the -n option to the command like this:

```
Exec=pcmanfm -n %U
```

Save the edited file, and thereafter, pcmanfm will always open in a new window unless you specifically tell it to open something in a new tab.

The feature to default to opening in a tab rather than a new window would be fine if it were workspace-aware. The difficulty that arises is that you may have pcmanfm open on some other desktop and you try to open a file and nothing (apparently) happens. If you hunt around on your other desktops, you'll find it, but it should default to opening in a new window if there is no open pcmanfm on the current desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I've Fedora 20 with LXDE. If I do a right-click and go to Desktop preferencies or if you type the following command:

```
pcmanfm --desktop-pref
```

Under the tab Advanced there is the option "Open folders from desktop in new window" that resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ubuntu LXDE, not Fedora.
That option for "pcmanfm --desktop-pref"  does not work for me.
I got a couple of errors, including a pop-up that says "Desktop manager is not active."
The answer I provided previously (editing the pcmanfm.desktop file) does work for me.

In particular, I'm running a Ubuntu server install with LXDE added
manually after installation, rather than "Lubuntu", so it may be something
particular to my configuration that causes the error, or perhaps it's a
difference between Fedora and Ubuntu, I don't know.
I'm just reporting what works for me.